# Can't login via RDP one laptop, one particular USER ID

Tags: remote-desktop

I just got a new laptop and I'm having a strange issue. I use RDP in my business, and have not ever had a problem with RDP.

With the new laptop, I can log in to my desktop remotely on all but one user ID. For some reason, when I use my main (administrator) login ID, I get an error

> Wrong user ID or password.

RDP still works on the old laptop. This looks like a Windows 10 issue to me. All other machines seem to connect fine. This new laptop is the first I've used that forces the Microsoft account connectivity. I'm wondering if that is part of the issue.

Anyone have any ideas?